# Setting up Xcode to work with SDL?

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, sdl

So I know C/C++ but I'm having so much trouble setting up SDL to work with XCode so I can start making actual applications. I've looked at tons of tutorials on the web, but they always have a part or two that make no sense what so ever in them. For example, a lot of tutorials say to download the Mac runtime and development SDL libraries, but there is no development library for the mac, only runtime. So I was hoping that the lovely people here could step me through the setup.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the runtime libraries are what you need. I think the development libraries are for Xcode 3.2 project templates or whatever, but I could be wrong...

Comment: I am interesting in what the differences between dev and runtime are.

Answer (score 0):

The following article shows how to work around the lack of SDL project templates for Xcode 4:

[Using SDL with Xcode 4](http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/using-sdl-with-xcode-4/)